# How do I get a warning in Visual Studio when async methods don't end in 'Async'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous

How can I get Visual Studio to give me a naming warning each time I create an asynchronous method that doesn't end in "Async"?

It's the recommended convention for asynchronous methods, but I often find myself forgetting to add that suffix and a warning would be useful.

Comment: Asynchronous code is now so ubiquitous that I don't see it as a practice anymore, unless you really have both versions.

Comment: "It's the recommended convention for async methods" is it? It's kind of assumed, now.

Comment: What we can do using Visual Studio Text Editor configurations or `.editorconfig` file, is limited to warn about methods with `async` modifier, we cannot apply the rule for methods which return `Task`.

Comment: @alexander that's ridiculous.  A method should only be asynchronous if it does something asynchronous.  I'm sure you're not suggesting that all methods do something asynchronous.

Comment: @rory.ap No, I'm suggesting that asynchronous calls are so common now that it doesn't warrant special treatment. You naturally think about checking which classes a method belongs to, what its return type is, etc. Yet we don't annotate method names with what classes they belong to, or what their arg and return types are. I'm saying to give async the same treatment. It's just "one of those things" you check on a function when you learn how to use it, without it being called out explicitly in a name.

Comment: Note all methods that perform potentially concurrent actions (ie. can run asynchronously) will use the `async` modifier, but should still use the same convention (`async` and `await` is an implementation detail, but the `Async` suffix should follow the semantics of the method).

Comment: Hopefully using `...Async` in the name goes the way of Hungarian Notation!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

From *Options*,

- Go to *Text Editor* → *Basic* → *Code Style* → Naming
- Select *Manage Specifications* and *Add New Specification*
- Select *Method*, tick all accessibility options and from *Modifiers*, select *Async*.
- Give the title as Async Method and save
- Now get into *Manage Naming Styles* and add New Style. Add Async as suffix and give it a name as AsyncSuffix, and then save
- Now press the plus sign and create new naming. Select specification as *Async Method*, select required Style as AsyncPostfix and *Severity* as *Suggestor*.
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and save

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Despite all these up-votes don't see how it works for me. No suggestions, warning, errors - nothing

Comment: @Kamarey after applying this rule. try closing your editor, reopen it and delete one of your async method without Async postfix and try adding again. It will start working, you may also consider to change severity to Warning.

Comment: This won;t catch async methods that don't use the modifier (ie. return `Task` but don't directly await).

Comment: My experience: the naming rule will work for a method, except it will not work when the method is declared on an interface.  https://gist.github.com/arthg/c46cb81921f8930d6e4c83858f198897

Comment: is there a fix for this @Arthur

Comment: it won't work on static methods :(

Answer (score 38):

In addition to Visual Studio Text Editor Settings, you can create portable, custom editor settings `.editorconfig` file. Visual Studio 2017 natively supports `.editorconfig` files.

By creating the `.editorconfig` file as part of the repository and pushing it to the repository, you can enforce consistent coding styles for everyone that works in that codebase, regardless of their Visual Studio Text Editor Settings.

> The Coding conventions you use on your personal projects may differ from
>   those used on your team's projects. EditorConfig files resolve this
>   problem by enabling you to have a configuration for each scenario.

> EditorConfig settings take precedence over global Visual Studio text
>   editor settings.

To do so:

1. In the *Solution Explorer*, select the Solution, Project or a folder in the project, depending on the scope which you want to apply the naming rule.
2. Right click and select *Add New Item* or Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Choose *Text File* file from *General* categories and enter `.editorconfig` as file name.

*Note: The [file location](https://editorconfig.org/#file-location) can be even in parent folder of your solution. It's not necessary to have it in solution.*

Paste the following content in the file:

```
# Top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*.{cs,vb}]

# Async methods should have "Async" suffix
dotnet_naming_rule.async_methods_end_in_async.symbols = any_async_methods
dotnet_naming_rule.async_methods_end_in_async.style = end_in_async
dotnet_naming_rule.async_methods_end_in_async.severity = suggestion

dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.applicable_kinds = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.required_modifiers = async

dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.required_suffix = Async
dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.word_separator =
```

More Information:

- [Create portable, custom editor settings with EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options??WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=vs-2017)
- [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/)

Comment: I discovered that actually, you don't need to "Add new item", you literally just need to drop the `.editorconfig` file in the same directory as the `.sln` file and it is detected.

Comment: The [file location](https://editorconfig.org/#file-location) can be even in parent folder of your solution. It's not necessary to have it in solution folder structure. Putting in project structure is just for having it available in VS to edit it.

Comment: This is pretty neat, the only problem I see is that this also applies to `async void` event handlers, which I don't want. Is there a way to exclude `async void` methods?

Answer (score 5):

The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers` analyzer offers this
under the rule VSTHRD200

More info here
https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD200.md

tl;dr:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" Version="17.1.46">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

Comment: I want to thank myself from the past for commenting the above. Also, tl;dr: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers" Version="17.1.46">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>`

Comment: And I can also confirm that it works perfectly in Jetbrains Rider as well. Besides this `Async` naming issue it also showed me a lot of new warnings. Thanks a lot