# How do we make VS2019 complain about methods that behave asyncronously but have names that aren't suffixed with "Async"?

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis

A few weeks ago, my VS2019 was making a raft of suggestions about various methods in one of our APIs, that behaved in an asyncronous way way (returned a task, contain awaited calls) but weren't named "...Async"

I put it on the todo list to review and fix as low priority, but now I come to look at it VS seems to have stopped making the suggestions.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972941/how-do-i-get-a-warning-in-visual-studio-when-async-methods-dont-end-in-async) was suggested as a duplicate; I've reviewed it and it might solve the query but I'm still puzzled for a few reasons:

- I don't recall ever having followed that procedure
- Source control doesn't indicate anyone ever put a .editorconfig file in the repo (and then later removed it)
- I was under the impression the suggestions were being made for methods that returned a `Task`, `await`ed something in the body but didn't have an `async` modifier, which the linked technique relies upon (but I might be remembering incorrectly here, and maybe I was looking at an asyncless interface rather than an async decorated implementation of an interface method)

So I guess my question is, aside from the technique in the linked possible-duplicate, is there any other way VS can come to make suggestions about asyncronously behaving methods being badly named? Some code analysis extensions I may have installed without realizing perhaps?

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972941/how-do-i-get-a-warning-in-visual-studio-when-async-methods-dont-end-in-async)?

Comment: Thanks @FrancescoB. - that will help. Though I'm certain I've never done that procedure before, so I'm still curious why my VS used to do it and now does not?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a warning in Visual Studio when async methods don't end in 'Async'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972941/how-do-i-get-a-warning-in-visual-studio-when-async-methods-dont-end-in-async)

Comment: Note the answers to that question (which does match this one) focus on methods with the `async` modifier which is a subset of asynchronous methods.

Comment: Yes, which is making me wonder. I thought the methods I was getting suggestions for *didn't* have an async modifier, but I might be remembering looking at the interface (which wouldn't have an async modifier, just a Task return type)

Comment: Did you find out whether it was an extension thing?

Comment: I've added MCA, Roslynator and AsyncFixer, but none of them seem to have generated the message.. I'll probably go with the process in the linked question and leave it as an open puzzle..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the tool NDepend integrated in Visual Studio, CI and Azure DevOps to use this code rule ([with NDepend a code rule is a textual C# LINQ query](https://www.ndepend.com/features/cqlinq#CQL)):

```
// <Name>Async method not suffixed with Async</Name>
warnif count > 0
from m in Application.Methods
where m.IsAsync && !m.SimpleName.EndsWith("Async")
select m
```

Here is the result of this rule on NopCommerce code base:

[image: NDepend code rule to detect async methods not suffixed with Async]

*Disclaimer: I work at NDepend*

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, there are a couple extensions that could be involved in this:

- Roslynator
- Microsoft Code Analysis

You can always check the installation date of your extensions by opening Extensions> Manage Extensions, clicking on them and looking to the right ("Date installed"):

[image: Manage extensions]