# How can async void event handlers be excluded from .editorconfig naming rules?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous, editorconfig

What I would like to achieve is the following:

The IDE, e.g. Visual Studio, should use a set of rules to determine whether a method name follows the following convention and issue a warning in case of a violation:

1. awaitable, asynchronous methods with the `Task` or `Task<T>` return type should receive the `Async` suffix, e.g. `public async Task<string> FetchMyStringAsync()`
2. non-awaitable, asynchronous methods as well as any other synchronous method should not have this suffix, e.g. `private async void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)` or `public bool IsValid(string input)`

By following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53973220/4308455) it is possible to create [naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules) in a *.editorconfig* file to get suggestions, warnings or errors when asynchronous methods do not have the `Async` suffix in C#:

```
# Async methods should have "Async" suffix
dotnet_naming_rule.async_methods_end_in_async.symbols = any_async_methods
dotnet_naming_rule.async_methods_end_in_async.style = end_in_async
dotnet_naming_rule.async_methods_end_in_async.severity = suggestion

dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.applicable_kinds = method
dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.required_modifiers = async

dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.required_prefix = 
dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.required_suffix = Async
dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.end_in_async.word_separator =
```

However, these rules will also apply to `async void` signatures, e.g. event handlers:

```cs
private async void OnSomeEventOccured(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await SomeOperationAsync();
}

private async Task SomeOperationAsync()
{
    // do some other asynchronous stuff here...
}
```

The editor will then suggest to change `async void OnSomeEventOccured()` to `async void OnSomeEventOccuredAsync()`, which I do not want.

How can the above rule set be changed to exclude `async void` method signatures and only apply them to `async Task`? If this isn't possible, as it seems based on my own research, is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

According to [Code-style naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules), if we want to specify to standardize async Task instead async void, then dotnet_naming_symbols.any_async_methods.required_modifiers = async Task should be specified

But in actual testing, such a specification does not really work. It does ignore async void, but the constraint displayed on the async Task is [CA1822: Mark members as static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1822)

[image]

I took a closer look at [Code-style naming rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules), which explains the reason:

[image]

Yes, Code-style naming rules are currently supported.

So if you can define the naming rules for async methods in editorconfig, but you cannot specify async void or async Task to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that `Task` is not a modifier, it's a type. Although this explains *why* it is the way it is with my configuration, this doesn't provide a solution to my problem. I appreciate the effort and I am open to solving this differently.